# SSRS Reporting Services reports to use css stylesheet with classes

Tags: css, sql-server, reporting-services

While working with reports, there is need to apply custom css class to various elements within the report like text boxes and rectangles. We can have these classes published on the server and load it using rc:Stylesheet option. However, not able to determine a way to apply specific classes to the elements within my report.

A similar query was posted by @royinomir at [Add css class to generated report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883544/add-css-class-to-generated-report)

The response received to that query is not very useful.